# C# force constructor's parameters to receive specific values

Tags: c#, constructor, compilation

how can I force constructor's parameters to have specific values?
In the example below I would like to have only 2-4 players.

I would like to have a compile error when I enter a wrong _numOfPlayers value.
Another way to warn the coder from using the constructor in a wrong way will be welcome.

```
    public class Rules
{
    public Rules(int _numOfPlayers)
    {

        numOfPlayers = _numOfPlayers;
    }
 public readonly int numOfPlayers;

}
```

A more complicated situation:

```
    public class Rules
{
    public Rules(int _numOfPlayers, int _money)
    {

        numOfPlayers = _numOfPlayers;
        money = _money;
    }
 public readonly int numOfPlayers;
 public readonly int money;

}
```

Here I would like to have only specific combinations:
2 players, 2000 money.
2 players, 1000 money.
3 players, 700 money.
4 players, 500 money.

How can I promise that?

Comment: A common way to do this is to throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` from within the constructor, if the number of players is not acceptable. This is only enforced at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: Why do you want this as a compile error? You would have to create a custom type that had the restraints you need. Any change to restraints would require a change to the type, or the addition of more types. A lot of overhead just to get a compile error. And if the money is not a range (as the number of players are), then you could simply make that property read-only and set it inside the constructor, based on the number of players passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no practical way to constrain types like this at compile-time in C#. I think the best you'll be able to do in your example is maybe create an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) that only has the valid values. Then your code won't compile if you using anything besides those values.

```
enum PlayerCount {Two = 2, Three, Four};
```

Then your constructor would look like this:

```
public Rules(PlayerCount count)
{
   numOfPlayers = (int)count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great Idea. How can I implement it with the more complicated situation, which I've just add to th post?

Comment: Enums are a strong suggestion but don't enforce anything beyond the underlying type `new Rules((PlayerCount)(-1))` This should still be backed up by `if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(PlayerCount), count)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));`